# Where can I find a rigorous proof of this statement in the literature? : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

In Wolfram MathWorld site at [Moebius Function topic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)
there is identity number 10, which states that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$.
Could you help me find a rigorous proof of this statement in the literature?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Landau's PhD thesis: https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3787

Comment: @MicahMilinovich, I think [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405966/where-can-i-find-a-rigorous-proof-of-this-statement-in-the-literature-sum#comment1040931_405966)'s an answer!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169675/127263

Comment: More generally, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k^{s}}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$. Your result follows from the fact that $s=1$ is a pole of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @Joseph Van Name: Unless I'm missing something, it's a lot subtler than the fact that $\zeta$ has a pole at $s=1$. You need to be able to justify the interchange of limits (otherwise, for example, the prime number theorem would be much easier than it is).

Comment: @JosephVanName This argument (together with an appropriate version of Abel's theorem for Dirichlet series) shows that *if the limit exists*, then it is equal to $0$. However, convergence is far from clear. Questions like this are subtle and convergence depends on distribution of zeros of zeta. For instance, convergence for all $s>1/2$ is equivalent to RH.

Comment: You are right. I was not being rigorous.

Comment: This also appears in Titchmarsh's book "The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function".

Answer (score 16):

Ayoub, *An Introduction to the Analytic Theory of Numbers*: Theorem 7.10 on p. 111.

Bateman and Diamond, *Analytic Number Theory: An Introductory Course*: Theorem 5.9 on p. 100.

Hlawka, Taschner, and Schoissengeier, *Geometric and Analytic Number Theory*: Corollary 4 on p. 123.

Jameson, *The Prime Number Theorem*: Theorem 3.4.5 on p. 134.

Montgomery and Vaughan, *Multiplicative Number Theory I: Classical Theory*: equation (8.8) on p. 248.

Narkiewicz, *The Development of Prime Number Theorey from Euclid to Hardy and Littlewood*: Theorem 5.20 on p. 239.

Overholt, *A Course in Analytic Number Theory*: pp. 52-54 shows convergence of $\sum \mu(n)/n$ implies the sum is $0$, the convergence of $\sum \mu(n)/n$ is equivalent to $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \to 0$, and that limit being $0$ is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem.

Titchmarsh, *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* (2nd ed.):
Theorem 3.13 on p. 62.

In the third and fourth references, the proof is essentially based on the following theorem.  If the Dirichlet series $f(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} b_n/n^s$ has bounded coefficients, so it converges for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$, and $f$ has an analytic continuation to the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ except for at worst a simple pole at $1$, with
$$
f(s) = \frac{\rho}{s-1} + c + O(s-1)
$$
near $s = 1$, then $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x} b_n \to \rho$ and $\sum_{n \leq x} b_n/n = \rho\log x + c + o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$.  In particular, if $\rho = 0$, meaning $f$ is analytic at $s = 1$ and $c = f(1)$, then $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x} b_n \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(1) = \sum_{n \geq 1} b_n/n$. Taking $f(s) = \sum \mu(n)/n^s = 1/\zeta(s)$, we get $(1/x)\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \to 0$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(n)/n = 0$ since $1/\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic on ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ with a zero at $s = 1$.